# Best speakers to simulate Iphone playback?

Tags: iphone, monitoring

Hi,
I got to do some jobs that should sound good on a nice set of speakers but also translate well to iphones.

In the past i have been emailing the mix myself and played it back on the phone to double check, but i would prefer to connect a set of tiny speakers instead during the mix.

How are my fellow sound designers handling this issue, and are there maybe recommendations for  a certain speaker which makes a good iphone simulation?

I have some cheap desktop speakers that come close but the iphone sounds even worst. :)

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 4):

I use a program called [airfoil](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/airfoil-speakers-touch/id311357351?mt=8) which lets you slave an iphone or ipod touch to your mac run computer over wifi.  It has a reliable 3 second lag time and can be triggered from qlab by routing it through soundflower.

Answer (score 3):

why not use an iPhone speaker impulse response?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will find what you are looking for dk... Even if you find speakers that have the same sonic signature like iPhone's it will not be the same size so that will cancel the effect!

I would go for a cheap iPhod Touch to do this job. It has the same speaker I think!

Answer (score 2):

keep sending it to your iphone. I check every advert mix on a couple of tv/computer monitor/laptop speakers :) It just has to be done... don't try take any shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I agree with Nikos. I'd just keep re-trying it on the iPhone until you feel you've got it right. Whenever I've got something I just try it out on a variety of places (car/TV/regular stereo speakers etc). Just remember that you'll get barely any bass response from the iPhone, anything below 1K is basically gone!

Answer (score 1):

I created an iPhone and iPad impulse response to simulate their speakers in a DAW. It will work in any convolution reverb that imports wav files. Enjoy :)

http://www.aaronbrownsound.com/free-impulse-responses-from-the-ipad-iphone-and-behritone-speakers/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best thing to do is what Nikos said but you if you want, you could try one of these mobile speaker things and see if that works any good I don't know..

[alt text http://www.ephekto.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Nokia-md-8-mini-speakers.jpg](http://www.ephekto.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Nokia-md-8-mini-speakers.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I read something in Bob Katz mastering book that debunks the "use cheap speakers" setup.

Answer (score 0):

For these things I use a program called Azul on iPhone. Still not realtime, but it takes practically every formt out there (at least the current ones), so you neither needs to convert the file nor email it to yourself!